# Could non-avian dinosaurs survive if introduced into modern world?

Tags: biology, hard-science, dinosaurs

Lets say Jurassic park somehow came to existence and someone cloned dinosaurs genetically identical to ones of the past and tried to keep them in a zoo.  Could the dinosaurs survive as is?

I'm specifically wondering if, given the change in atmosphere and environment over such a large time period, non-avian dinosaurs could survive in a modern world who's environment is so different from what they were evolved for?  For now ignore the issue with finding prey and a successful evolutionary niche, their being fed by some zoo staff or something.

Comment: "Dinosaurs" is a very large group.  It's like asking if "mammals" could have survived in an earlier time period.

Comment: Which kind of [tag:hard-science] do you expect here? I am not aware of anybody who has written papers on the integration of non avian dinosaurs into present biomes.